# Тачи(touch) в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

При таче персонаж двигается , но только один раз.После даже при повторном нажатии ничего не происходит.

```
public float moveSpeedPlayer = 7;
public GameObject Player;
void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    { 
    Player.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + moveSpeedPlayer * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: [GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)

Comment: не знаю, может Translate использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё раз посмотрите вот на эту строку

```
Player.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + moveSpeedPlayer * Time.deltaTime);
```

Полагаю, на самом деле персонаж постоянно немного двигается, т.к. Time.deltaTime не постоянная)

Поясню - вы назначаете в позицию персонажа transform.position.y + moveSpeedPlayer * Time.deltaTime - но т.к. объект на котором висит скрипт, я полагаю, не двигается, то и позиция вашего персонажа устанавливается в эту точку и только немного дрожит из-за непостоянности Time.deltaTime.

Answer (score 0):

Может, написать так?

```
Player.transform.position = new Vector2(Player.transform.position.x, Player.transform.position.y + moveSpeedPlayer * Time.deltaTime);
```

Новую позицию игрока берём как координата этого же игрока по X и координата этого же игрока по Y плюс скорость на время.